# MySql Server install issue using latest C++ Redistributable 2015-2019

Tags: mysql, vcredist

just wondering if anyone has encountered an issue with installing the latest version of MySql Server, v.8 and above.

I was running into issues because it wasn't recognizing that i had the latest c++ redistributable (x86 and 64 bit) which puts all of 2015, 2017 and 2019 into the one file. This is only a recent change that microsoft have made.

Before installing it would say that no 2019 redist.. has been found on the system, which isn't the case. I tried removing the 2015-2019 file and installing individual redistributables for each year (2015 and 2017) but also didn't work, bit of a head scratcher. There is no single redistributable for 2019, its just the 3 in 1 version available, so to speak.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: The [2019 Redist](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) also contains the Universal Runtime. Just because its a rollup of 2015/17 does not mean that there are not things in the 2019 redist that ARE NOT IN the individual 2015/17 redist. Think of it as a 2019 release + rollup of 2015 & 17

Comment: If you had the 2015 and 2017 installed and then you install the 2019, you will see that the individual 2015 and 2017 redists get removed. I imagine MS were trying to reduce the confusion that is in almost everyones minds about these libraries

Answer (score 1):

Downlaod the latest supported Visual C++ here.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

then select one of this that support your operating system.

x86: vc_redist.x86.exe

x64: vc_redist.x64.exe

ARM64: vc_redist.arm64.exe

Comment: This worked for me - all I needed was the x64 redist from this page to get a noinstaller version of mysql community server 8 running. For posterity, in case the link stops working, the name of the download on the page is 'Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019.'

Answer (score 0):

Try installing MySql Server using the installer rather than the whole package. It will show required minimum requirements and in case it does met, it will show the requirement which you can download directly from there using the icons from right.